# ssh remote command not working as expected (problems with read)

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, remote-execution

I have a script on my server named `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Select an option [1-4]: " option
echo "You have selected $option"
```

When I run it through ssh manually, I see this:

```
me@me:~$ ssh root@server
root@server's password:
[...]
root@server:~# bash test.sh
Select an option [1-4]: 48
You have selected 48
```

When I run it as ssh remote command, I see this:

```
me@me:~$ ssh root@server 'bash test.sh'
root@server's password: 
48
You have selected 48
```

I am unsatisfied with this output because it's missing `Select an option [1-4]:` prompt string and the original script which from has I derived `test.sh` contains a lot of interactive dialogue strings like this and I need them all.

I know that `read` prints it's prompt to `stderr` so I tried to start the script with following commands in case if stderr is omitted, but the output stays still the same:

```
ssh root@server 'bash test.sh >&2'
ssh root@server 'bash test.sh' >&2
ssh root@server 'bash test.sh 2>&1'
ssh root@server 'bash test.sh' 2>&1
```

Why this is happening and how to make ssh remote command work as expected?

**UPD**

I have changed the `test.sh` to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Connected
read -p "Select an option [1-4]: " option
echo "You have selected $option"
```

but the output still missing the prompt string:

```
me@me:~$ ssh root@server 'bash test.sh'
root@server's password: 
Connected
66
You have selected 66
```

Comment: I've updated the question. Prompt is still missing.

Comment: If you just want to Print the line, then use `echo` to print the line and then use `read` to read value. Its a workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `-t` option in `ssh` to assign a pseudo-terminal to `ssh` session:

```
ssh -q -t root@server 'bash test.sh'
```